# Arduino wifi server created many clients and lost connection

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

I write wifi server for Arduino(Node MCU).

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char *ssid = "mywifi";  // You will connect your phone to this Access Point
const char *pw = "qwerty123"; // and this is the password
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 1); // From RoboRemo app, connect to this IP
IPAddress netmask(255, 255, 255, 0);
const int port = 9876; // and this port

WiFiServer server(port);
WiFiClient client;


char cmd[100]; // stores the command chars received from RoboRemo
int cmdIndex;
unsigned long lastCmdTime = 60000;
unsigned long aliveSentTime = 0;


void setup() {

  delay(1000);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, netmask); // configure ip address for softAP 
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, pw); // configure ssid and password for softAP

  server.begin(); // start TCP server

  Serial.println("ESP8266 RC receiver 1.1 powered by RoboRemo");
  Serial.println((String)"SSID: " + ssid + "  PASS: " + pw);
  Serial.println((String)"RoboRemo app must connect to " + ip.toString() + ":" + port);

}

void loop() {


  if(!client.connected()) {
    client = server.available();
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("new client");
  if(client.available()) {
    char c = (char)client.read(); // read char from client (RoboRemo app)
    Serial.println((String)c);
  } 

}
```

When I start this server it work fain. I connect to it from my android normaly. Then I open telnet on my android and tried connect to server. But on server side created many clients and after created connect lost.

When I started server I have this log

```
SID: mywifi  PASS: qwerty123
RoboRemo app must connect to 192.168.0.1:9876
```

When I tried connect to server from `telnet` I have this log:

```
SSID: mywifi  PASS: qwerty123
RoboRemo app must connect to 192.168.0.1:9876
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
new client
```

.....

And on `android telnet` side I have error:

```
Error while receive from server: recvfron filed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new client` trace is not at the correct place, when a client is connected, each execution of `loop` will print it. Then "new client" trace is printed a lot.
In order to print `new client` only when server get it, you could procced like this :

```
void loop() {
  if(!client.connected()) {
     client = server.available();
     if(client.connected()) {
       Serial.println("new client");
     }
     return;
  }
  if(client.available()) {
    char c = (char)client.read(); // read char from client (RoboRemo app)
    Serial.println((String)c);
  } 
}
```